# Login to SkyDrive using Live SDK

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, onedrive, live-sdk

I'm migrating my Windows Phone 7.1 app to Windows 8. Unfortunatly, I have some problems with loging to SkyDrive using Live SDK on Windows 8. I'm using this code:

```
        LiveAuthClient authenticationClient = new LiveAuthClient();
        try
        {
            LiveLoginResult initializeResult = await authenticationClient.InitializeAsync(new[] {"wl.offline_access", "wl.signin", "wl.skydrive_update"});
            if (initializeResult.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
            {
                _currentSession = initializeResult.Session;
            }
            else
            {
                LiveLoginResult loginResult = await authenticationClient.LoginAsync(new[] {"wl.offline_access", "wl.signin", "wl.skydrive_update"});
                if (loginResult.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
                {
                    _currentSession = loginResult.Session;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Not connected :(
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw GetDetailedException(ex);
        }
```

The LiveLoginResult allways returns NotConnected in it's Status property. When I run the code, the form where I should agree to access my Live Account (it should be shown automatically) is not shown. What could be the problem? Can anyone help me with this stuff?
Thanks a lot!

***Edit:**
I have already associated my app with the store - it still doesn't work. What is more, I have created a completly new app (in the store and in Visual Studio) and I have also associated it with the store - it also doesn't work with the code I have provided. The form where the user should agree, that the My App can use his SkyDrive account is not shown. Can any one help me with this? I have already wasted so many hours, but I'm sure this is just a simple hurdle I can't jump over.

***Edit 2:**
Could sb just say whether the code is ok? I wish I know where I should try to find the solution. In the code or in my Win Store Dashboard?

Comment: Make sure you have enabled the correct capabilities in the manifest. That mistake gets me every time.

Comment: Which should I choose for Live SDK? I have selected all of them for a test, still doesn't work. All properties in LiveLoginResult have default values - 'nulls' and 'NotCOnnected'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. I have wasted so many hours, but finally the reason was that sth wrong happend when updating my system. I have just checked it on a virtual machine. Everything is ok now.